Is there any way to create submit on Enter without event listeners?
Is there any way to create submit on Enter without event listeners? I run into a problem in my project. I have there some modals, that I want to submit with enter (there are not any forms). And one form using CKEditor for email templates and my problem is that when i press the enter button in doesn't break line in CKEditor because the eventListener catch the keydown event of other modals although not calling callback function. Has someone ideas how can I fix that?
Here is my useKeyDown hook code
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useKeyDown = (callback: () => void, keys: Array<string>) => {
  const onKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    const wasAnyKeyPressed = keys.some((key) => event.key === key);
    if (wasAnyKeyPressed) {
      event.preventDefault();
      callback();
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
    };
  }, [onKeyDown]);
};

export default useKeyDown;

Example of usage hook
useKeyDown(() => {
      if (condition) {
        handleConfirm();
      }
    }, ["Enter"]);

Usage of CKEditor
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

<CKEditor
  editor={ClassicEditor}
  data={newComment}
  config={{ placeholder: t("history.comment") }}
  onChange={handleOnChange}
/>

And CKEditorConfig
export const editorConfig: EditorConfig = {
  language: "en",
  toolbar: {
    removeItems: [
      "Source",
      "Save",
      "Templates",
      "NewPage",
      "Preview",
      "Print",
      "Cut",
      "Find",
      "Replace",
      "Copy",
      "Paste",
      "PasteText",
      "PasteFromWord",
      "SelectAll",
      "Scayt",
      "Form",
      "Checkbox",
      "Radio",
      "TextField",
      "Textarea",
      "Select",
      "Button",
      "ImageButton",
      "HiddenField",
      "RemoveFormat",
      "Subscript",
      "Superscript",
      "CopyFormatting",
      "BidiLtr",
      "BidiRtl",
      "Language",
      "CreateDiv",
      "Indent",
      "Outdent",
      "Anchor",
      "Flash",
      "Table",
      "HorizontalRule",
      "PageBreak",
      "Iframe",
      "Styles",
      "Font",
      "Maximize",
      "ShowBlocks",
      "Format",
      "FontSize",
      "About",
    ],
  },
};

